# Binary filter for max value of SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.  I am very new to SQL and really do not even know how to start going about solving this so I apologize in advance for the lack of already attempted solutions.  A simplified example of my current SQL Query is as follows:

```
USE [DataBase]
GO
SELECT [ID]
      ,[Value1]
      ,[Max1]
      ,[Value2]
      ,[Max2]
FROM [DataTable]
```

Which yields something like so:

```
[ID] [Value1] [Max1] [Value2] [Max2]
[1]    [2]     [0]      [9]     [1]
[1]    [4]     [0]      [3]     [0]
[1]    [8]     [1]      [5]     [0]
[1]    [5]     [0]      [6]     [0]
[2]    [1]     [0]      [1]     [0]
[2]    [6]     [1]      [4]     [0]
[2]    [3]     [0]      [3]     [0]
[2]    [2]     [0]      [5]     [1]
```

I am trying to get my datatable (DataTable) to select the value corresponding to the binary indicator (Max1 and Max2 columns for Value1 and Value2 respectively) that it is the maximum value for that ID.  Basically I am trying to get the above table to become:

```
[ID] [Value1] [Value2]
[1]    [8]      [9]
[2]    [6]      [5]
```

If it is much simpler to create a separate data frame for each variable (Value1 is in a separate resultant data frame as Value2), that is fine as well.

Thank you

Comment: Do you need to limit your search to values with the "binary indicator" on or does that always flag the maximum value already? It almost sounds like Matt's answer would work too.

Comment: The way the data is stored, there will always be that "binary indicator" signifying that the corresponding row contains the max value for the matching variable.

Comment: So it sounds like you could use either answer below although vkp's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation to pick up the values corresponding to the binary values 1.

```
select 
[ID]
,max(case when [Max1] = 1 then [Value1] end) as value1
,max(case when [Max2] = 1 then [Value2] end) as value2
from [DataTable]
group by [ID]
```

Comment: nice yep I missed the Max1 and Max2 being and indicator of which record he wants

Comment: @Matt The indicator is redundant, for this question anyway. You might argue it's better to stick with the simpler query.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT [ID]
      ,MAX([Value1]) as Value1
      ,MAX([Value2]) as Value2
FROM [DataTable]
GROUP BY
    [ID]
```

Comment: This answer is also sufficient as the binary indicator is redundant and pulls the max in the same way